# Allow access to only one website for standard user

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer

On my Personal Computer (Windows 10 Pro), I've two local accounts.

- John - Admin
- Doe - Standard User

The thing I'm trying to enforce is that when John logs in, allow him access to any and all websites. But when Doe logs in, allow him access to only one website. To do this, I tried the `IE Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Proxy server -> Advanced` path and specifying the exception rule as follows:

[image: ss]

The problem with this approach was there fold:

1. This did block all the websites except youtubekids but the target website did not load graphics/content upon loading. I could only see the header/search bar and nothing else thereby defeating the purpose of allowing access to it
2. John had to undo this proxy every time he logged in to allow access to all sites
3. John also had to make sure he enabled the proxy again before signing out or shutting down the computer which is not a desirable effect

So I was wondering if there is an automated way of doing this and also one that works nicely (i.e. the allowable website loading fully and not partially along with this being automated and not having to manually change settings whenever John logs in or signs out.

I also read something about Firewall rules but got no clue how to enforce it.

Answer (score 1):

This will never work. With browser settings or via firewall rules.

Websites are not simple web-pages anymore. They are very complicated beasts pulling in content/resources from multiple sources.

In order to load a site properly you need to allow access to most of these sources else it just won't work properly.
So you need to identify each source (which for many sites is impossible unless you have access to the sites source-code), determine which of those are really needed and which ones (like advertisements) can be omitted. Then you need to setup the whitelist of the ones you want to allow.

That is not the whole story. With parts of the sites content missing the web-browser will in most cases not be able to render the site properly, because it is now also missing information about the layout of those missing pieces.
Say you filtered an advertisement out that showed in the middle of the page with the web-site text flowing around it on both sides. Without information on the original size of that advertisement (often stored inside the ad, not in the web-site itself) the browser can't figure out how the render the text around it properly.
This is by the way the same problem that ad-blocker plugins face when filtering ads from a web-page. They typically replace the ads themselves with dummy place-holder objects so the browser has something to work with.

This looks like an XY problem.
You are seeking help for an issue with solution Y, that you need to eventually solve problem X.
But Y is not the right solution in the first place.

It seems from your example image your goal is to limit web-access for your children.
There are better ways to do that.
"Parental controls" is a standard feature of Windows 10 (search for "Family Settings" in Windows).
It allows you to specify which sites your kids can visit and offers some other interresting functions as well.

Comment: That's surprising actually. I would have thought the approach would much more simpler. On paper the requirement looks pretty doable - Allow only website "x" for user A and allow all websites for user B. I guess the mechanics are quite different than I thought. A shame really....